# Add wordpress sitemap to my main sitemap.xml

Tags: wordpress, sitemap

I have a main site and a wordpress blog. My main site `example.com` has a `sh` script that generates the file. My Wordpress has a sitemap generated by Yoast. I need to access that file and add it to my main `sitemap.xml`. I thought it would be best to create an `XMLHttpRequest` and I created a `get-blog-routes.js` which looks like:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "https://www.example.com/blog/post-sitemap.xml");
xhr.responseType = "document";

xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log(xhr.response, xhr.responseXML);
  }
}
xhr.onerror = function() {
  console.log("Error while getting XML.");
}

xhr.send();
```

My issues are:

1. I am having some trouble getting the `responseXML` (I think it may be due to testing this locally).
2. I am unsure exactly how to export this data to my `generate-sitemap.sh` file

---

**UPDATE**

I have tried adding this to my `sh` file by doing:

```
BLOG_ROUTES=(`curl -s -L -G 'https://www.example.com/blog/post- 
sitemap.xml'| xpath \ 'urlset/url'`)

for URL in "${BLOG_ROUTES[@]}"
do
  echo $URL >> $SITEMAP
done
```

However it gets formatted really weird, any ideas of how to do this properly?